# Can MTP be configured to show the root?

Tags: root-access, 6.0-marshmallow, mtp

I have a rooted device running Android 6.

When I connect it via USB, I can browse files via MTP, but it is limited the the `/sdcard` folder, for instance I can see `Downloads` and `DCIM` but I can't access `/system/app`.

**QUESTION:** Is there a setting or trick that would allow me to access `/` via MTP?

Very technical procedures such as recompiling system programs are OK too.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to modify MTP mode, but my workaround would be to enable USB debugging/ADB and use a program like QtADB.

Comment: @Robert: Thanks but I am explicitely asking about MTP, it is for a solution that must be compatible with any MTP client.

Comment: @acejavelin FYI, you can delete your own comment: no need to flag it for a moderator to remove.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is no, you can't... You are not really looking at /sdcard but at a database of what that card contains provided by `External Storage` and possibly `Media Storage`. MTP has replaced USB Mass Storage (which would allow this) for a variety of reasons, many are security reasons, and they are encoded deep within the Android source code in multiple areas. MTP is specifically designed to only give access to user files (/sdcard and /storage/{volname}) and nothing else. I don't think you will find a way, root or otherwise, to this without heavily modifying the base code of Android

Comment: "*You are not really looking at /sdcard but at a database of what that card contains provided by External Storage and possibly Media Storage*" -- can we have something *verifiable* that supports this claim?

Comment: @Firelord In a quick search I was not able to find verification of that specifically, but my claim can be based on the fact that in Marshmallow devices require `External Storage` app to work. If you delete data on this app and connect via MTP, nothing will show up (directory will be empty on PC), if you then reboot and allow the database for the app to rebuild then connect to the PC, the files will show. Logic says that app is giving access to the files, although I understand that correlation may not be causation in this case. If I find more specific verification of this later I will share it.